# How to build electron application with assets folder by Electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have built an application with electron-builder. There was a video in `media` folder in the development area. But when I built the application I figure out the video folder replaced with `asar` file in a resource folder in C://Programs.

I want videos to have in `media` folder in production. How can I do that

Comment: Don't specify `--asar` in your build script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try with `asar: false` in your `package.json` file. But, this is not the recommended way to do it.

The best you can do is to add the resources you want to keep outside the asar file with the `extraResources` directive:

```json
"build": {
    "extraResources": [
        {
            "from": "../media",
            "to": "media",
            "filter": [
                "**/*",
                "!*.mp3",
            ]
        }
    ],

    "asar": false,


}
```

Comment: Dude I've been looking for this whole night! Thanks a lot, bless you! 

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me... What did work was to specify the directory whose contents I wanted to access post-build in the same format as specified for the `files` configuration.

electron-builder.json:

```
{
...
"extraResources": [
  "src/assets/my-assets/*"
],
...
}
```

After the build, you will find your folder at the same location as the asar file  (.../app/resources/src/assets/my-assets), under resources. There's no need to specify `asar: false`.

On the main process, if you use `__dirname`, it will end with `app.asar`. The assets can be accessed using:

```
// Removing 8 characters to remove "app.asar"
let strippedPath = __dirname.substring(0, __dirname.length - 8);
let execPath = '\"' + strippedPath + 'src\\assets\\my-assets' + '\"';
```

Now `execPath` can be appended to with whatever needs to be executed from the assets folder.

Comment: Thanks, finally simple explanation and solution. For the path you can use `path.join( __dirname, "../assets/my-asset")`